# zeep.exceptions.Fault: The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, soap, zeep

I am integrating BSE StarMF (https://github.com/utkarshohm/mf-platform-bse) in Django 2.0.2 and python 3.6. I am registering user through `create_user_bse(user_id)`. While calling `getPassword`, I am receiving this error:

> "zeep.exceptions.Fault: The message with To
>   'http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFUploadService/MFUploadService.svc/Basic'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree."